# How do I force the Chrome devtools to scale up with zoom level?

Tags: google-chrome, web, google-chrome-devtools, zooming, scaling

In Chrome, when one increases the zoom of the browser, devtools does not account for this. For example, when using the mobile emulator, you can see that media queries are not applied when they should be. Instead of applying the query at it's corresponding `px`, it offsets that application to account for the zoom. Is there a way to offset devtools as well to account for this?

Or, better yet, is there a way to scale Chrome itself on Gnome 40 so I don't need to use the browser's zoom?